# Performance with LIKE vs CONTAINS using full-text indexing

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table with a large(ish) amount of rows 500k, MSSQL Server 2008. I have a column which holds a nvarchar product ID which is usually 15 characters in length, alphabetical and numerical e.g. `FF93F348HJKCF5HW9` . I would like to be able to search for this product ID with the best performance. I have done some research into using Full-Text indexing on this column and I dont really think that using full-text indexing using `CONTAINS` offers any benefit over using `LIKE '%%'`. This looks to be down to the fact Full-text indexing is more beneficial when searching for whole words, rather than a series of characters.

Can somebody confirm/deny this for me?

Comment: Why do you need to search for partial product Ids? I'd just index the column and search for exact matches or at least without the leading wildcard. If your application does in fact need to search for partial Ids make this a separate function and query not the default behaviour as I assume the need is rare.

Comment: Searching for partial product IDs will be used on a 'auto complete' like textbox on the web interface. Typing a partial ID will show a down down list of possible matches whilst tying.

Comment: So there is no need to cater for a leading wildcard then. This will slow down all queries (requiring a full scan) to allow for the remote possibility someone might randomly decide to type a piece from the middle. I'd at least make partial match a checkbox not selected by default.

Comment: Sure, that is not a problem, but my question is regarding `CONTAINS` and `LIKE`, in this case is there any performance benefit using  `CONTAINS` with full-text indexing over using `LIKE`

Comment: Full-Text indexing is about searching for language words - your data doesn't contain words, just a sequence of characters - I would expect that LIKE would actually be faster (if the data is indexed). Note that contains is meant for searching for word-like structures: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx

Comment: @N West, Pretty much what I thought was the case, submit as an answer and I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: AFAIK FTS won't index the various substrings of the ProductId that would be required to make this search at all efficient. I suppose you could do this yourself though as only 15 entries required per ProductId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full-Text indexing is about searching for language words in unstructured text data. Your data doesn't contain words, just a sequence of characters.

I haven't tested this, but I would expect that `LIKE` would actually be faster, as long as your data is indexed. `CONTAINS` is meant for searching for words & word-like structures.

If your requirement is for "auto-complete", then `LIKE` will perform pretty well since the optimizer will use an INDEX SEEK when you search for something such as `LIKE 'F5521%'`.

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) explains the basics of the `CONTAINS` keyword.